# É possível obter o usuário do firebase pelo UID?

Tags: ionic, firebase, angular, ionic3

A duvida consiste no seguinte problema:

Estou com um projeto utilizando firebase e ionic 3.
Estou utilizando o modo de autenticação via E-mail, na qual tem o e-mail e o UID armazenados.

Por exemplo:
Tenho 2 usuários cadastrados na base.

1_ teste@email.com UID = 123

2_ teste2@email.com UID = 321

No meu código eu tenho um elemento mensagem que possui o id de quem está enviando, por exemplo:

Mensagem 1 = descricao: "descricao", idUsuario: "123"

Estou logado com o usuário de UID 321 e quero recuperar o usuário de UID 123 para exibir o e-mail dele, como faço isso?

Eu não queria armazenar no database do firebase, mas como nao tem outra maneira, então, alguém saberia me informar como faço para criar uma tela de cadastro que cadastra via email/senha e que armazena no firebase esses dados.

PS: estou tentando utilizando autenticação via token do usuário logado para escrever no database, mas para realizar o cadastro não há nenhum token, por isso não estou conseguindo.

Esta assim:

```
 return this.http
  .post(this.urlDataBase + email + '/user.json?auth=' + token, usuario)
  .map((response: Response) => {
    console.log(response);
    return response.json();
  });
```

Mas não está salvando no firebase, está dando erro 400:

```
Response {_body: "{↵  "error" : "Invalid path: Invalid token in path"↵}↵", status: 400, ok: false, statusText: "Bad Request", headers: Headers, …}
```

Comment: segundo esta resposta não e possível: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673708/how-do-i-return-a-list-of-users-if-i-use-the-firebase-simple-username-password

Comment: Só utilizando o authentication não é possível. Você terá de utilizar a database

Comment: Obrigado.
Sacanagem não ter um meio de acessar esses dados...

Comment: Os dados da sua mensagem estão armazenados no Data Base Real Time do firebase?? quando vc salva não pode colocar logo o e-mail não?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforme dito no [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673708), não é possível fazer essa leitura do Firebase diretamente, mas existem algumas outras formas de se fazer as validações para que possa ser realizado operações de CRUD diretamente no firebase.

*When using email / password authentication in Firebase Authentication (previously known as Firebase SimpleLogin), your user's email and password combination is securely stored separately from the data actually stored in your Firebase.*

*This barrier between the data in your Firebase and your users' email / password hash combinations is by design: we want to make it easier for you to (1) develop your application, (2) prevent any accidental user credential leaks, and (3) still give you total flexibility with how to store your user data in Firebase.*

*That means that we only store the email address / password hash combination and nothing else, so it is up to you to decide how to store actual user data in your Firebase. *

GOOGLE TRANSLATE - TRADUÇÃO

Ao usar a autenticação de e-mail / senha no Firebase Authentication (anteriormente conhecido como Firebase SimpleLogin), a combinação de e-mail e senha do usuário é armazenada de maneira segura separadamente dos dados armazenados no Firebase.

Essa barreira entre os dados em seu Firebase e as combinações de hash de senha / email dos usuários é por design: queremos facilitar para você (1) desenvolver seu aplicativo, (2) evitar qualquer vazamento acidental de credenciais do usuário e (3) ainda oferece flexibilidade total sobre como armazenar seus dados de usuário no Firebase.

Isso significa que apenas armazenamos a combinação de hash de endereço de e-mail / senha e nada mais. Por isso, cabe a você decidir como armazenar dados reais do usuário no seu Firebase.

---

Bem você pode pegar o ID do usuário e armazenar esses dados no seu Firebase em um local como `/users/$id` e usar o `Firebase Security Rules Language` para determinar o acesso de leitura / gravação a esses dados. O ID e o email exclusivos de seus usuários já estão na variável auth que você usará ao redigir as regras.

Outra alternativa é

- A aplicação entrar com um acesso "Admin" (apenas de Leitura e/ou escrita [depende das necessidades])
- Pegar uma lista de usuários do Firebase
- Utilizar a lista para fazer as validações necessárias

Desse modo você estaria logado e poderá fazer as operações de criação de usuário, atualização de dados, apagar um usuário, ler usuários etc.

Answer (score 1):

Eu passei pelo mesmo problema. Não existe outro jeito a não ser armazenar o UID + informações deste usuário dentro do Firestore/Real DataBase.

O Firestore Authentication na verdade é um serviço isolado de autenticação de usuário, assim como o Cognito da AWS onde informações de acesso são guardadas dentro desse serviço.

Buscando um pouco, percebi que eu deveria armazenar dentro de uma Collection "User" os dados do usuário (nome, sobrenome, email, cidade...) e também o UID como chave (id).

O fluxo foi basicamente :

1) O usuário faz o registro na aplicação
2) O Firestore Authentication gera um novo autenticado
3) Automaticamente eu crio um novo DOC dentro da Collection "User" tendo o ID idêntico ao UID gerado dentro do FA.

Dentro do fórum oficial do Firestore eu encontrei muitas pessoas falando que isso não seria "incorreto", pois o UID do usuário não oferece nenhuma possibilidade de acesso aos dados sensíveis e também não é um.